# How to set Python 3 as default app?

Tags: python

I have installed Python 3 after working on Python 2, but it's not working and my old Python scripts are just opening in notepads and unable to run on Python interpreter.

When I install Python 2 again it's working. I tried to set Python 3 in the environment variables path, but it does not work.  What should I do?

Comment: Please tell us what "does not work" mean. What error do you get? What's the behavior you are seeing?

Comment: I can,t open the .py files with python interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to be working on multiple python versions and their respective subpackages it's high time you started using python virtual environment.[Why should you use python virtual environment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5vscPTWKOk)

By creating such virtual environments you can rest assured and work on projects dealing with different versions.

Installation:

```
sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
sudo easy_install virtualenv
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

Creating virtual environment folder:

```
mkdir ~/.virtualenvironment
```

Project and files which depend on this virtual env:

```
virtualenv ~/virtualenvironment/my_new_app
```

Activating the virtual env:

```
cd ~/virtualenvironment/my_new_app/bin
source activate
```

[Reference](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/how-to-use-python-virtualenv)

Comment: Thanks a lot @sudip